# Rails3 create a global variable throughout application upon initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently we have a method in `application_controller.rb` which initialises a global variable or returns its value if it has been initialized.

Problem is this is being called upon each request, and its redundant because the variable is initialized after the first request.

How can I move this method to `application.rb` and have it run once upon Rails' initialisation

```
    config.after_initialize do
      begin
        @global_user = User.find(100)
      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.info "Error finding the Global User"
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thats an instance variable - not a global. Global variables in Ruby use the sigil `$` eg. `$global_user`. I also don't think this is actually a good idea at all. Use caching instead if you want to avoid a database query. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @max thanks for your input. Can you take a look at my proposed solution below. What would be the cons for such a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a potential solution

In `application.rb` I run the following code

```
    config.after_initialize do
      begin
        config.global_user = User.find(100)
      rescue => e
        Rails.logger.info "Error finding the Global Objects Account"
      end
    end
```

And then at that point my Application has a reference to Application.config.global_user which can be used anywhere throughout the app